# changing background color on every clock tick

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to add a changing background color on every tick of this digital clock, but I have no idea where to start. Here's my tick part of the code

```
public void start()
{
    if ( runner==null) runner =new Thread(this);
    runner.start();
}
public void run()
{
    while(runner==Thread.currentThread())
    {
        repaint();
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
        catch(InterruptedException e) {}

    }
}
```

Additional information, if this helps:

```
public Clockclass()
{
  super ("javaclock"); setSize(300,100);
  setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  setVisible(true);
  clockFont= new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD,50);
  Container contentArea =getContentPane();
  ClockPanel timeDisplay = new ClockPanel();
 contentArea.add(timeDisplay);
setContentPane(contentArea); 
 start();
}

class ClockPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent (Graphics painter)
    {
        painter.setColor(Color.cyan);
        painter.fillRect(0,0,300,100);
        painter.setFont(clockFont);
        painter.setColor(Color.white);
        painter.drawString(timeNow(), 60, 40);
    }
}

public String timeNow(){
Calendar now =Calendar.getInstance();
int hrs=now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int min=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int sec=now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
String time= zero(hrs)+":"+zero(min)+":"+zero(sec);
return time;
}


public String zero(int num)
{
    String number= (num<10)?("0"+num):(""+num);
    return number;

    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you absolaulty have to, use a `javax.swing.Timer`, it will execute tick event notification within the Event Dispatching Thread.

This would then allow you to simply supply a new color or trigger a color change within the `ClockPanel` either by directly passing the color in or by automatically adjusting the color...

You should always call `super.paintComponent`.  `paintComponent` should also be `protected`, there is no reason any body should ever be calling outside of the classes context

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Clock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Clock();
    }

    public Clock() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int count;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    count++;
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(count % 2 == 0 ? Color.RED : Color.YELLOW);
            int dimeter = Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight());
            int x = (getWidth() - dimeter) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight()- dimeter) / 2;
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, dimeter, dimeter);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```